# objective-c - iOS - textfield to int variable

Tags: objective-c, ios, variables, textfield

Problem with textfield and integer variable. I use textfield to write a number and in function I work with this number.

```
int changeid = [idchoice text];
```

But I must retype, how?

Answer (score 8):

```
int changeid = [idchoice.text intValue];
```

Done.